# Is there ever a situation where $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{0}{f(x)} \neq 0$?

Tags: calculus, limits

> Is there ever a situation where $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{0}{f(x)} \neq 0$?

I am currently grading a calculus 3 assignment, and the answer key that the professor has provided me is trying to evaluate the following limit: 
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{0}{4x^4}$$
If I was to solve this limit, I would simply say that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{0}{4x^4} = \lim_{x \to 0} 0 = 0$. On the answer key, however, the professor uses L'Hopital's Rule 4 times to get the same conclusion. Am I missing something, or would my method be sufficient?

Comment: Not everyone is lucky to have good teachers.

Comment: @Blake Splitter: Your method is superior. It's also the standard method for this scenario. Just make sure the denominator is nonzero for all nonzero $x$ sufficiently close to zero.

Comment: That's weird. The numerator is zero and the denominator is not (as you are taking a limit). The only situation where I can kind of imagine that the answer would not be zero, is if $0$ is not in the denominator's domain, like $\frac{0}{\sqrt{x-4}}$, but why considering such situations?

Comment: $\frac{0}{f(x)}=0$ for all $x$ for which it is defined. Is there ever a case when $\lim_{x\to 0} 0$ is not zero?

Comment: To answer the question in your title: If $f(x)$ is the constant $0$ function, the limit would not exist.

Comment: Nothing can go to 0 quicker than 0. So it is always zero, (unless it is undefined or does not exist).